# EC2 Can't connect to your instance via Session Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, session-management, aws-session-manager

EC2 Can't connect to your instance via Session Manager, the EC2 have same role as different EC2 that have Session Manager access. EC2 that don't work is in same subnet that EC2 that work. Any suggestions why I can't connect?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DescribeAssociation",
                "ssm:GetDeployablePatchSnapshotForInstance",
                "ssm:GetDocument",
                "ssm:DescribeDocument",
                "ssm:GetManifest",
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:ListAssociations",
                "ssm:ListInstanceAssociations",
                "ssm:PutInventory",
                "ssm:PutComplianceItems",
                "ssm:PutConfigurePackageResult",
                "ssm:UpdateAssociationStatus",
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceAssociationStatus",
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2messages:AcknowledgeMessage",
                "ec2messages:DeleteMessage",
                "ec2messages:FailMessage",
                "ec2messages:GetEndpoint",
                "ec2messages:GetMessages",
                "ec2messages:SendReply"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is policy attached to it

Comment: Is the SSM agent installed on the instance?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you are trying to do (eg are you using the Session Manager console, or the command line) and the _exact_ error message? Is the EC2 instance listed in the Session Manager console and the error occurs _after_ you attempt to connect, or is your problem that the EC2 instance is _not_ appearing in the Session Manager console? More information, please.